# jpa criteria builder auto add id criteria when compare by other fields

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

Actually it's hard to come up with a better question, please read more for details:

I have an entity:

```java
class A {
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private User creator;
   ...
}
```

and class User

```java
class User {
   ...
   private Long id;
   private String empNm;
   private String engNm;
   ...
}
```

In my Specification Builder class, I have these two lines of code to compare creator's `empNm` and `engNm` with search value:

```java
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("creator").get("empNm"), searchLike));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("creator").get("engNm"), searchLike));
```

However, I've observed that it automatically adds more condition when query, it compares

```sql
where
   A.creator_id = User.id
```

I know this is true because when I remove those two lines, the condition above disappears.

I have searched around but couldn't find any related information about this as it hard to describe in technical term of JPA what kind of feature this is.

Please help to show me a way to remove the id comparison because here I only need to compare by other fields `empNm` and `engNm`,

Comment: see it is basically joining the table 'A' with 'User' table. That is correct only, The purpose of "@ManyToOne" is  that only.

Comment: Do we have a way to forcefully stop that? @Lucia

Comment: what is your usecase? 
You want to just search for "User" entities ?
In that case you have to just use criteria for User, your root will be from User

Comment: In my case, there are some data that don't have id, but the result of search should include those data. Because the condition `A.creator_id = User.id` not related to what the user wants to search, so it's quite confusing in this case.

Comment: your usecase is not clear.  if User and A  are entities properly designed. THen there is no way that there are some data with id as null.

Comment: So we should not handle this case in the code, instead trying to make the data integrity intact. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. How are those data getting inserted without id? logically there has to be id field for both the entities right? ANd join will always happen on unique field.

Comment: thank you, in conclusion, it's the data problem, we should not find a way to hack around it.